# PHP - Function to Load XML / Modify / Save

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, str-replace

I would like to open the file, made the modification, save it as it was before, but my function does not work, and I'm not sure why.

Here is my function:

```
function modifyXml($candidateFile){

$xml = simplexml_load_file($candidateFile);

$searches = ["\n</DESIGNATION_PLU>"];
$replacements = ['</DESIGNATION_PLU>'];

$xml = str_replace(  $searches, $replacements, $xml->asXml() ) ;
file_put_contents($candidateFile, $xml);
}
```

This is where I'm using it, as part of another function:

```
foreach ($candidateFiles as $candidateFile) {

            modifyXml($candidateFile);

            $this->processXml($candidateFile, $destdir);

            if ($this->input->getOption('cleanup')) {
                $this->addInfo("Deleting source XML file: " . basename($candidateFile));
                @unlink($candidateFile);
            }

            $completedPercentage = ( ++$i == $fileCount) ? 100 : floor($i * $singleFilePercentage);
            $this->addInfo("$completedPercentage% complete.");
        }
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _...made the modification, save it as it was before.._ Doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @B001ᛦ Sorry, I would like to load up XML, replace text inside it, and save it back by using original name

Comment: @B001ᛦ Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions, anyone??

Comment: Nothing at all?((((

Comment: Is this a follow on from the last question which is still open or something new?

Comment: Hi, when you say "does not work", what do you mean exactly? Is the file not saved, or saved with the wrong contents, or do you get an error message...? Please also provide a small sample of the input, and the desired output, that could be used to test solutions - a [mcve]. Without that information, it's very hard for anyone to do more than guess at what's wrong.